# $F_{q^d}/F_q$ a finite field extension, a question about the homomorphism: $Aut_{F_q}(F_{q^d})\to Aut(F^{\times}_{q^d})$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I want to find the range of such homomorphism and to what Frobenius endomorphism of $q$, i.e $Fr_q$, is sent to? what is the kernel?

Can you help me with hints?

Thanks!
Even keywords to use for better google searching.

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the question. There is a very natural homomorphism that simply sends a power of the Frobenius to its restriction to the multiplicative group. But there are others. So I don't think there is **the** homomorphism?? Anyway, The first group is cyclic of order $d$, so the range and the kernel will be cyclic of complementary orders.

Comment: Complementary orders, i.e. d-1 and d+1. which one is d-1 and which one is d+1?1

Comment: A homomorphic image of a cyclic group of order $d$ is cyclic of order $a$ for some $a\mid d$. The kernel then has "complementary" order $d/a$. All according to the first isomorphism theorem
$$G/\mathrm{Ker}(f)\simeq \mathrm{Im}(f).$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen what is the order of the image of the Frobenius homomorphism? thnaks.

Comment: Depends on the homomorphism! Under the restriction homomorphism the image of the Frobenius to the multiplicative grou  has order $d$. But with other homomorphisms $g$, the order of $g(Fr_q)$ can become any factor of $d$.

Answer (score 1):

Here the group of field automorphisms $Aut_{\Bbb{F}_q}(\Bbb{F}_{q^d})$ is known to be cyclic of order $d$, and generated by the Frobenius $F$.

The latter group consists of automorphisms of the multiplicative group $G=\Bbb{F}_{q^d}^*$. The group $G$ is known to be cyclic of order $q^d-1$. If $g\in G$ is a generator, a homomorphism $\phi: G\to G$ is uniquely determined by where it sends $g$. So we known that $\phi(g)=g^j$ for some natural number $j$. Call this homomorphism $\phi_j$. For it to be an automorphism of $G$ we need it to be surjective (because $G$ is finite surjectivitiy implies bijectivity). This happens if and only if $\phi_j(g)=g^j$ is another generater of $G$ if and only if $\gcd(j,q^d-1)=1$. As $\phi_j\circ\phi_k=\phi_{jk}$ with the product $jk$ calculated modulo $q^d-1$ we arrive at the description
$$Aut(G)\simeq \Bbb{Z}_{q^d-1}^*.$$

So any homomorphism from $Aut_{\Bbb{F}_q}(\Bbb{F}_{q^d})$ to $Aut(G)$ is really a homomorphism $\psi$ from $C_d$ to $\Bbb{Z}_{q^d-1}^*$. Again, $\psi$ is uniquely determined by where it maps $F$. Because $F^d=id$ we get $\psi(F)^d=\phi_1$
as the only constraing. So whenever $a^d\equiv1\pmod{q^d-1}$, we get a well defined homomorphism $\psi_a$ uniquely determined by $\psi_a(F)=\phi_a$.

If the order of $a$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{q^d-1}^*$ is $m$, then we must have $m\mid d$. In that case $\operatorname{Im}(\psi_a)=\langle \phi_a\rangle\simeq C_m$, and
$\operatorname{Ker}(\psi_a)=\langle F^m\rangle\simeq C_{d/m}$. It may be worth observing that this is in line with the first isomorphism theorem.

---

However, there is a *very natural* homomorphism that simply maps $F$ to its restriction to the multiplicative group. Really, $F=\phi_q$. That special homomorphism is the homomorphism $\psi_q$ from above. It is not unnatural to think that wherever this question came from, this restriction (we really just exclude zero from the domain and the range) is the intended homomorphism. However, it is impossible to say without seeing the source. Should this be the intended interpretation, then the order of $a=q$ is $m=d$, and the homomorphism $\psi=\psi_q$ is injective. Hence its kernel is trivial and the image consists of powers of the Frobenius.